# Should I include the write-ups I have published in newspapers in my CV?

Tags: cv, literature

I am a student of English literature.

Since 2018, I have regularly published short stories and literary articles in national and international newspapers. The number is around 20.

Should I mention these published write-ups in my academic CV? If yes, then what is the right method of mentioning it in the CV?

Answer (score 20):

You should absolutely mention successful work in your CV if it's relevant to the position/program that you are applying to.

With so many, it is best to mention the number of submissions and the nature of the work and periodicals and individually cite only a couple of the most recent or relevant ones.

Answer (score 10):

**Yes.** To build upon [dubious's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/193523/33210), list them under a section such as *Public outreach*, *Media outreach*, or *Popular press*.
I would look at the CV's for the faculty (usually listed on their website) to see if/how they list these articles.

As a caveat, the articles are not peer-reviewed so do not try to present them as such.
Some people will value them on your CV, others will not.
As long as you do not lie, this should not hurt you.
Only help you or be netural on your CV.